# method get(String) is undefined for the type Object when getting location from Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-facebook

I have a GraphUserCallback that returns a graphObject of the requested user information, I think put this into a Map as below.

```
Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
responseMap = graphObject.asMap();
```

I then grab each data item I need from the map e.g:

```
birthday = responseMap.get("birthday").toString();
```

This works well, apart from when I try to get the users location, the responseMap location item is actually an object containing name and id.

So I try to do

```
location = responseMap.get("location").get("name").toString();
```

However I get the error:

> method get(String) is undefined for the type Object

What can I do to get the 'name' field from the object in the 'location' of the responseMap

I should not that the structure seems to be a JSON object as if I do

```
location = responseMap.get("location").toString();
```

I get what looks like a JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the `responseMap`, then you can get the `name` of the location like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)responseMap.get("location");
String name = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("name"));
```